# What are the minimum set of interfaces I need to implement to use ActiveX Control in Visual Basic 6.0

Tags: c++, activex

I am attempting to create a minimal ActiveX control using C++, without the use of ATL or MFC. So far, I have created a COM object which implements a custom dual interface with a single method, AboutBox(). I would now like to be able to display a small rectangle in the VB6 design-time environment, but otherwise not show any GUI at run-time (for instance, the Common Dialog control). Currently I don't envisage having any events.

By a sequence of events which I entirely admit not being able to explain (I have been hacking the registry to make my CLSIDs/Type Library keys look like a "real control"'s settings), I have managed to get the control to appear in the VB6 Components dialogue. It now even loads, and I get a black "icon" on the toolbar representing my control. I can drag this onto a form. However, it crashes out with "System Error &H80004005".

Whilst debugging the control's QueryInterface method, I get the following IIDs being queried:

- IQuickActivate
- IOleControl
- IPersistStreamInit
- IPersistStream
- IPersistStorage
- IViewObject
- IOleObject

How many of these do I actually have to implement? The only thing I consider I will be using is properties.

(Note: The actual error code is E_FAIL  Unspecified failure 0x80004005).

Comment: That's readily available, the stuff you can skip is [documented here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms690316%28v=vs.85%29.aspx).  You'd of course be wise to start with a known-to-work sample.  The [existing ones](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa728874%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) use MFC.  You can google plenty more.

Comment: I had already found that. The annoying thing is that whilst it talks about optional methods, I want to know the optional interfaces! And specifically,  what interfaces are optional for the VB6 IDE. The docs seem to suggest that the minimum is IUnknown and Self-Register - but that is no more than a basic COM component.